# is the action invoked on Windows.Forms.Form executed on main thread in this example?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to write a server in C# and have a fundamental question on thread delegation and communication.

```
    using System.Windows.Forms;

// main thread..
callbackform = new Form();
callbackform.createControl();
int dummy = callbackform.Handle.ToInt32();

// here I create a new thread to connect to a server and handle messages from server

// main thread loops indefinitely
Application.run(new ApplicationContext());
```

Now, Form implements ISynchronizeInvoke interface. So if I want to execute a method synchronously or asynchronously on the main  STA 
thread, can I use  callbackform.InvokeRequired/BeginInvoke/EndInvoke/Invoke(...) functions?

Does the Form/Control/Handle objects create new thread in which case the thread they manage is not the same as main thread and the action I delegate to Form won't actually execute on main STA thread?

Is this the correct understanding or am I missing something fundamental here? I am beginning to write a non-GUI server using C#.

Comment: If you don't have a thread that calls Application.Run() then calling Control.Begin/Invoke() will **not** work as usual.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? The main thread in this case is in a message loop. What do I need to do in order to make this work?

Comment: [Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) and [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e8s7xdd(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If ApplicationContext is your MainForm then there is nothing special here, answer is Yes.